# Insert Query is not inserting anything into the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO new_emails (from,subject,message,to,filename,fileurl) VALUES ('$id','$stripsubj','$content','$toids','$upload_name','$att')");
```

Firstly, I am aware that mysql_query is depreciated, and I will be re-doing the whole script at some point in the near future to accommodate this.

My main problem is that this query is not currently inserting anything into the database, and I haven't the faintest clue why. Unfortunately I don't have access to any phpMyAdmin logs/SQL logs that can help me debug this problem.

I have been working on this for a while so I am hoping I have something pretty stupid and not noticed.

The columns inside "new_emails" are: id,from,savedtodb,subject,message,to,filename,fileurl

The ID is auto_increment, and savedtodb is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, which is why I am leaving them out.

Have I done anything particularly stupid or is there a deeper reason why this isn't working?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Since your `id` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you shouldn't be using `'$id',` then.

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that $id is actually the user's ID, and is being included from a separate file holding the session data.

Comment: Does `mysql_error` return anything? It will usually tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @user151000 - what happens if there's an apostrophe included in the email?

Comment: Gordon's answer is the solution. You're using 2 reserved words.

Comment: You should get into the habit of reading the error messages that mysql gives back on failure. You probably could have solved this one yourself in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from` and `to` are reserved words.  You need backticks for them:

```
INSERT INTO new_emails (`from`, subject, message, `to`, filename, fileurl)
    VALUES ('$id', '$stripsubj', '$content', '$toids', '$upload_name', '$att')
```

Comment: You beautiful human being. Thank you for the quick response! Definitely time for me to now take a break :p

Comment: @Tim . . .  Not to be preachy, but you should get into the habit of writing your SQL statements to be more readable.  Splitting them on multiple lines (i.e. separate lines for `select`/`insert`/`update`, `from`, and `where`) and putting spaces after commas might help your code be more readable and easier to prevent problems.

Comment: ...not to mention using error reporting ;-) which would have given the OP some insight.

Comment: @GordonLinoff not to be preachy, but it isn't my question, nor my query. I just meant I was busy trying to get more info from the poster and you saw the problem right away. Not sure why you @ signed me.

Comment: I appreciate all of the comments nevertheless. You can never stop learning, and we all make mistakes. Cheers for the help all :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible errors:

1) You may not have selected the database using mysql_selct_db or while declaring the connection.

2) Maybe you didn't escape the single quotes. MySQL hates single quotes, and would make an error if it finds any in the input.

Comment: While both of these are true, there is a syntax error in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It seems that backticking 'from' and 'to' has done the trick!